# How can I upgrade gcc (and all of its libraries) without root

Tags: node.js, linux, gcc, root

I have a shared hosting machine on GoDaddy and I want to deploy a sveltekit app. The problem is that sveltekit requires node version `16`. In the server `node` was not installed so I installed it with nvm.

When running `node index.js`, with node v16 some libraries turned out as missing.

```
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
```

Since I don't have root access either, I tried compiling from source but I broke the system and had to recover it with a backup.

I have read that compiling GCC and dependencies like GLIBC from source is quite difficult because you have to match all of the versions correctly.

Is there an easy way to do this or I need to look for other hosting that has node updated? As I said in the title, I don't have root access so I'll have to install newer GCC version only for my user.

Comment: This is not `GCC`, but the (system) `libc` and `libstdc++`. GCC is the compiler and will generally use whatever is available. That's also the cause of the problem here: `node` was built on a newer system than yours, and `node` therefore expects the `libc` from the build system, not your older local system.

Comment: If you need to update libc in most cases I means you need to update whole system. Looks like you'd better switch your hosting, i.e. use some cloud like AWS, GCP or Azure where distro etc is up do date and under your control.

Comment: @MSalters and is it possibl eto update libstdc and libstdc++ without root?

Comment: @i6iesma: No, that's fairly obvious. `libc` is a critical system component. If you could upgrade it, you could also replace it with `libc-evil`, for everyone on the system.